# how to use Search rest api in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, search-criteria

How to get items using search rest apis,example: I want to search watch in mogento2,how can i get the data from rest apis.

Tried like this : http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=watch

But i gives an error message like this:

> {"message":"Request name 'watch' doesn't exist"}.

Actually watches data is there.

Answer (score 8):

Try:

http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=watch

The possible values for requestName include;

- quick_search_container
- advanced_search_container
- catalog_view_container

Note: The filters vary for each requestName, see `Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml` for more details.

Comment: Wow.. now that´s a useless response! :D (From a frontend point of view) ;) Guess we will need a custom api for this as well :/

Answer (score 0):

Pass the correct params to make work search API.

> Method: GET
>
> Request URL:
>   http://localhost/magento2/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=watch

**Params:**

```
  searchCriteria[requestName]                        = quick_search_container
  searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field] = search_term
  searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value] = watch
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "80.6521797180175800"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 40,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "80.6521797180175800"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 43,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 42,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 41,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "score",
                    "value": "76.1715030670166000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "aggregations": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "name": "category_bucket",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "3",
                        "metrics": [
                            "3",
                            "9"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "6",
                        "metrics": [
                            "6",
                            "9"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "7",
                        "metrics": [
                            "7",
                            "4"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "8",
                        "metrics": [
                            "8",
                            "4"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "bucket_names": [
            "category_bucket"
        ]
    },
    "search_criteria": {
        "request_name": "quick_search_container",
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "search_term",
                        "value": "watch",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 9
}
```